# SSIS failing - I think due to windows folder permission

Tags: windows, ssis, permissions

This is the set up:
I have an SSIS package deployed to SSISDB.
I have a stored procedure that I can run to execute this package.
Finally, I have a SQL Server Agent job which runs this stored procedure.

This is what happens:
(1) When I run this stored procedure in SQL Management Studio window, it kicks off the SSIS package, and the package completes with no error. (2) However, when I run the SQL Server Agent job, it kicks off the SSIS package, but the package gets an error.

What is failing:
Within the SSIS package, there is a step that runs something (a .bat file) in C:\ of the SQL Server box. The fact that when I do (1) it runs ok, but when I do (2) it fails, tell me this has something to do with permission on the .bat file.

Question: How can I know what windows IDs are involved in (1) vs (2) so I can ask my Windows Admin to check the permissions?

EDIT: This is the error msg.

SFTP Delete Datafile:Error: In Executing "c:\program files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" "/script=\dcmfs01\Datafile05\BBG_DataLicense\BBG_Instruments\script\Delete.txt /parameter BBG_Instruments.dat" at "", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".

Not sure how helpful this is, but adding this additional info. The error msg simply says it couldn't execute the command. Doesn't say why. Also, I am noticing now that in my original msg, I said it was a .bat file. But it's actually a .com file... not sure if that has any significance but want to point that out.

Comment: Based on that error, I don't think it's that winscp.com can't be accessed, but something is  going wrong in the execution.  So, the next step is to capture the error.  Set The StandardErrorVariable and change FailTaskIfReturnCodeIsNotSuccessValue to false.  Then you'll need to write the variable out to an information event.  I can add more to the answer, if you need more details on that.

Comment: Add `/log=c:\some\path\where\the\agent\can\write\to\winscp.log` to WinSCP commandline and post the log. + Show us the WinSCP script. + See also [SFTP file transfer in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32853720/850848) and [SQL Server agent for scheduling SFTP using WinSCP under SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32853720/850848).

Comment: Mark, I am not sure what you are describing. Sounds like some kind of setting in SSIS to see a more detailed error message? Yes, that would be helpful.

Comment: You are executing `"c:\program files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" "/script=\dcmfs01\Datafile05\BBG_DataLicense\BBG_Instruments\script\Delete.txt /parameter BBG_Instruments.dat"` (though I assume the quotes around the arguments are not an actual part of the command, otherwise the syntax won't be correct). I'm asking you to add `/log=c:\some\path\where\the\agent\can\write\to\winscp.log` to that command.

Comment: Martin, I tried that and I see it writes something to the log. HOWEVER, I am no longer getting the error I was... I am not sure what changed. BUT if I were to get the same error I was getting before, I wonder if adding this log would've done anything because the error I was getting seemed like an error in executing winscp.com VS winscp.com getting kicked off and getting some kind of error within the application. Hmmm.

Comment: Enabling logging will unlikely fix any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Check the ssis logs.  In SSMS, go to Integration Services Catalogs and drilldown to your project.  Right click on the project and go to reports> All executions.  Find one that failed and click on overview.  The id that it is executed under will be in the caller section noted below.

I think this will most likely be the sql agent service account, but I'm not sure if it switches context to the database engine because you are calling it through the procedure.

[image]

**EDIT**

This is how to capture more details from a process task error.

Add a string variable at the package level:

[image]

Configure the error variable in the process task:

[image]

Add a script task that executes on failure:

[image]

Configure the script task to read the variable:

[image]

Fire an error and read the variable like below:

```
public void Main()
{
     Dts.Events.FireError(0, "<Put the source task name here>", Dts.Variables["User::Errors"].Value.ToString(), "", 0);
}
```

Comment: Mark, thank you for that guidance. I was able to see that ID using your steps. However, that ID, had admin rights on the SQL Server box, so it should've had the rights to execute the .bat file that the SSIS package is calling. Hmmmm... Is it possible the "Caller" ID is different from the ID that ends up being used to execute the .bat file?

Comment: @AndrewYi Was the user SQL agent or SQL database engine?  Also, could you please add the actual error message to the original question?

Comment: Mark, thank you for following up. I added the error msg in my original post. Not sure how helpful that message is. But it's there for you to take a look. On the failed run (the one run as a job) was by the sql agent service account. On the succeeded run (the one run in the SQL Window logged in as myself) was by my ID

Comment: Hi @AndrewYi, I saw in the comments above that it is working now.  I would recommend capturing the error message from the process for future errors.  Do this by supplying a variable for the `StandardErrorVariable` and then write that to the ssis log or capture `OnVariableChanged' event and set the variable to raise that event.

Comment: Mark, I never did that so this is new to me. I do see something called StandardErrorVariable in the task editor. I will have to Google this for more detailed instructions on how to utilize this. Thank you for pointing me in this direction. Please let me know if there is anything further you might add.

Comment: @AndrewYi  I'll add some detail about how to capture a process error

Comment: Mark, I tried searching for how to use StandardErrorVariable and I am still not sure what to do with this. Or what the expectation is. Am I to expect that this will allow me to see a more detailed error message? The problem is, if I take the same command I am trying to run in the Execute Process task and run it in the DOS window, it works. But when it runs in SSIS, it fails and all I get is The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0" It would be great if I can see more detail than this. This is what I think your method will do so I am anxious to find out.

Comment: Mark. Actually I see that you edited your earlier response and there you added the details on how to use StandardErrorVariable. I follow everything you did, except for the script task part. When the error happens and the script task fires, where/how does it take the contents of the error variable and write it to somewhere I can go and see what got written?

Comment: If you are debugging in VS, either look in the OUTPUT view or the execution results tab.  When running from SSISDB catalog on the server, right click the project > reports > all executions and look at the most recent execution.  It will be logged as an error there.  If more questions come up, I'd say let's mark this one answered and create a new question focused on the new issue.

Comment: Mark, ahhhh I think I get what you are saying. I will try this and report back.

Comment: Mark, I think I did everything you described, but now, in addition to the error on the Execute Process task, I am also seemingly getting an error on the Script task. (How do you put screenshots in your messages like you did above? I wish I can show you my screen.) The error I am getting on the Script task says this.    Script Task To See Detailed Error:Error: The element cannot be found in a collection. This error happens when you try to retrieve an element from a collection on a container during execution of the package and the element is not there.

Comment: you'll have to open a new question, but most likely you have to add the variable to the ReadOnlyVariables list on the first tab of the script task

Comment: I did that. I created a user variable called "error". Assigned to the StandardErrorVariable in the Execute Process task. And in the Script task, made it ReadOnlyVariables. And then copy pasted your script. Where you had "<Put the source task name here>", I put in the name of my Execute Process task. That was the only part I wasn't sure if I did correct.

Comment: Sounds all good to me.  Just create a new question about it with screen shots and we can look

Comment: I am following few other leads on this. When I am ready to post a follow up question, I will do that. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Mark, I posted a followup question with detailed screenshots. I'm not sure how I can invite you to that question... I hope you will be able to find it.